# Drawing on an image with TikZ using own coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I do a lot of mapping, and regularly draw on images using the scheme outlined earlier ([Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)) on a 0-1/0-1 grid. I need to produce multiple scalings of the same mappings and it is inconvenient to recalculate the coordinates each time - I would like to be able to input the lower left and upper right coordinates, and to set these at some arbitrary value depending on the map chosen. How can I impose a different scale than 0-1, for example Y 0.322 to 1.779 and X 33.5 to 99.7?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.5,0.6) rectangle (0.7,0.8);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, the image should be placed exactly as before, only the coordinate system for the overlay is changed. Using the standard scheme it is scaled at 0 to 1. If I draw at 0.5,0.5 that would be central. I want to be able to set coordinates say X runs 10 to 20 and Y 30 to 40 then (15,20) would produce the same central overlay. If that is not clear I will expand the question. For example the coordinates could be longitude and latitude. London would have the same coordinates for a map of the world or a map of the UK.

Comment: OK that would set the coordinate of the bottom left (i.e the latitude and longitude at bottom left), but the scale would still be in cm. What I need to do is to set the coordinates (latitude/longitude) of the upper right as well (basically setting up a set of axes over the image).

Comment: I've tidied up a bit by converting my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the image at `(33.5,0.322)`, this will be the appropriate coordinate within the picture. This won't affect the placement of the image within the page - the coordinates are internal to the `tikzpicture`.

That is, you can do something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (33.5,0.322) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}}; 
  \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (34,0.922) rectangle (34.7,1.722); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: adjusted origin]

You obviously don't want to set `x` and `y` here. At least, not in the way you are doing since that is specifically designed to set up the 0-1 coordinates.

Perhaps you want to adjust them something like this:

```
\newlength\iwidth
\newlength\iheight
\settoheight\iheight{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\settowidth\iwidth{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\iwidth/66.27,y=\iheight/1.457]% 1.779-0.322=1.457; 99.77-33.5=66.27
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (33.5,0.322) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (34,0.922) rectangle (34.7,1.722);
  \draw[blue,ultra thick] (33.5,0.322) rectangle (99.77,1.779);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: adjusted scales]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newlength\iwidth
\newlength\iheight
\settoheight\iheight{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\settowidth\iwidth{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\iwidth/66.27,y=\iheight/1.457]% 1.779-0.322=1.457; 99.77-33.5=66.27
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (33.5,0.322) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (34,0.922) rectangle (34.7,1.722);
  \draw[blue,ultra thick] (33.5,0.322) rectangle (99.77,1.779);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is looking good. Will do some contemplation when I have a clear head tomorrow.

Comment: Probably worth adding for any confused readers that 1.457 is (1.779-0.322) and 66.27 is (99.77-33.5). This is great. I'll be able to encapsulate this in an environment.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Thanks for the suggestion. I've added a comment with this.