# How to creat tcolor box like this?

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox

[image]

I'm trying to make tcolorbox like this above and I don't know what is the right way to do it...

This is possible to make tcolorbox like this? (The ABC can be at the center instead...)?

I tried few times and I really don't know how (I think to put the image as watermark, but the the image cropped or something else...)

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294491/ if this can help you.

Comment: @heblyx: Why a `tcolorbox`? Is it necessary?

Comment: @MarianG. - Yes because I want to to this in box and maby put some titles...

Comment: what is the problem: create `tcolorbox` or its placing on image? For design `tcolorbox` see the package manual.  What you try so far? Question as it is is to broad and also unclear.

Comment: But when there is an image the second box is beside it and I'm trying to avoid from it...

Comment: @Zarko, can you give me example? because I didn't succeed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset
    {
        enhanced,
        left=8mm,
        right=8mm,
        boxrule=0.4pt,
        colback=red!5!white,
        boxrule=1pt,
        colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
        width=(\linewidth-4pt)/2,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0)(pic) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \draw [ultra thick,red](current bounding box.north east) rectangle (current bounding box.south west);
    \node at ([yshift=-2.5cm] pic.center)
    {\begin{tcolorbox}
    \centering ABC
    \end{tcolorbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Giving some opacity to `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset
    {
        enhanced,
        left=8mm,
        right=8mm,
        boxrule=0.4pt,
        colback=red!5!white,
        boxrule=1pt,
        colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
        width=(\linewidth-4pt)/2,
         }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0)(pic) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \draw [ultra thick,red](current bounding box.north east) rectangle (current bounding box.south west);
    \node[] at ([yshift=-1.25cm] pic.center)
    {\begin{tcolorbox}[
    standard jigsaw,
    opacityback=0.2,  % this works only in combination with the key "standard jigsaw"
]
    \centering ABC
    \end{tcolorbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if you want to add frame to image is possible?

Comment: Sure, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you!! BTW the frame can be without space (between the image and the frame)?

Comment: So as I understand there is no way to do it with `tcolorbox`, right?

Comment: I think, I did not understand your main question rightly. But it is possible to remove the space between image and frame. Please look at my last edited answer.